# Load Balancing akka-http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using akka-http, my **build.sbt** configuration is:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.4.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-http-experimental_2.11" % "2.4.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-http-spray-json-experimental_2.11" % "2.4.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-slf4j_2.11" % "2.4.2"
```

I am exposing a simple REST api with only one GET url
foo is a function that returns a Future

```
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system", config)
implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

val route: Route = {
  get {
    path("foo") {
      complete { foo }
    }
  }
}
```

**The web-service is expected to have a lot of calls**, and I want to make the service redundant in case of failure, so I want to have two instances running simultaneously to handle all the requests.

**1) what is the best way to have two intances of the web-service handling the requests simultaneously?, with an external load balancer or with some magic (wich I don't know) inside akka/akka-http ?


2) What are the principal parameters I have to tune up to improve perfomance?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930057/akka-http-java-api-respond-with-result-of-an-actor-call/34845060#34845060) demonstrates how to make an Actor call from within a `Route`.

If you combine that technique with the [clustering](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/index-network.html) capabilities within Akka you should be able to get the job done.

Have your Route send a message to a [`Router`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/routing.html) that will dispatch the message to 1 of N [remotely deployed Actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/routing.html#Remote_Deployed_Routees) (from your question it sounds like a [round robin](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/routing.html#RoundRobinPool_and_RoundRobinGroup) router is what you want).

```
class HttpResponseActor extends Actor {

  def foo : HttpResponse = ??? // Not specified in question

  override def receive = {
    case _ : HttpRequest => foo 
  }
}

import akka.actor.{ Address, AddressFromURIString }
import akka.remote.routing.RemoteRouterConfig

val addresses = Seq(Address("akka.tcp", "remotesys", "otherhost", 1234),
                    AddressFromURIString("akka.tcp://othersys@anotherhost:1234"))

val routerRemote = 
  system.actorOf(RemoteRouterConfig(RoundRobinPool(5), addresses).props(Props[HttpResponseActor]))
```

The remote Actor responds with the HttpResponse.  This Response can [go through the Router or directly back to the Route](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/routing.html#Senders).

The Route sticks the answer in a [`complete`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/route-directives/complete.html#complete) Directive to return back to the client.

```
val route = 
  get {
    path("foo") {
      onComplete((routerRemote ? request).mapTo[HttpResponse]) {
        case Success(response) => complete(response)
        case Failure(ex) => complete((InternalServerError, s"Actor not playing nice: ${ex.getMessage}"))
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Ramon, thanks for the answer!!!, can I ask you two more questions?
1) If I use actors I loose the backpresure control that streams provide me?
2) where I have to call my foo function?

Comment: @GeorgeC, you are welcome for the answer.  1) I don't think you'll lose back pressure, but I'm not 100% sure.  I don't know the effects of having a Route call `onComplete`, this could be converted into a `mapAsync` or `mapAsyncAwait`.  2) I have ammended my answer to retain your original `foo` function.  Happy hacking.