# how to respond to a request with a dependency on another actor?

Tags: akka, akka-http

this might be a stupid question, but I need to ask since I havent found an answer to it yet. I have used the akka-http with routing with the typical routing pattern of a path with a
complete with a HttpRequest.

For instance:

```
~ path("reactJS") {
  complete(
    HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, Source.fromFile(reactJS).mkString))
  )
}
```

However, I would like to have a separate actor that handles a file system and then, in my mind, I would like the server to pass the request over to the file handler actor. So my question would be, how would one naturally do a complete of a request with a dependency on another actor? I guess then the server would have a routing looking like:

```
 ~ path("patient" / IntNumber) { index =>
      FileHandler ! index
   }

class FileHandler extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case msg:Int => sender() ! file handling

}
```

and the serving of the request would have to be a case in the receive method of the server, right?

looking into:[How to respond with the result of an actor call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930057/how-to-respond-with-the-result-of-an-actor-call?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use the ask pattern (`?`) and then use the `onComplete` directive within your routing tree to handle the `Future` that comes back from the ask.  Taking your example, and modifying it a bit to show how you could leverage ask is shown below:

```
path("patient" / IntNumber) { index =>
  import akka.pattern.ask
  implicit val timeout = akka.util.Timeout(10 seconds)
  val fut = (fileHandlerActor ? index).mapTo[String]
  onComplete(fut){
    case util.Success(fileData) => 
      complete(HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(
        ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, fileData))

    case util.Failure(ex) =>
      complete(HttpResponse(StatusCodes.InternalServerError))
  }
}
```

The assumption here is that your actor is responding with a String that is to become the HTTP response entity.  Also, that timeout is a requirement of using ask, but you could very easily define it elsewhere in your code, as long as it's in scope here.

Comment: I think I am having problems reproducing this as a working code (unspecified value parameters: data:Source[ByteString, Any])

Comment: dont you need to write onComplete (fut)?

Comment: @stian, yes, u are correct,  I made all of those changes without checking for compilation.  I added the correct call to `onComplete` now.  Sorry.

Comment: it was actually fun to try to figure it out too:)